# Executing dotnet ef migrations remove only reverts model snapshot

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, migration

We have a EF project with multiple migrations being applied almost weekly to our database. I have to remove and add a new migration because I made a typo in a property of a model and I need it to be re-created.

I followed the usual steps:

```
dotnet update database MOST_RECENT_CORRECT_MIGRATION -c CONTEXT_NAME

dotnet ef migrations remove
```

The last command should revert model snapshot changes and delete the migrations cs and designer.cs files, but instead it only reverts the model snapshot and it doesn't deletes the previous migration. Until a few migrations back it worked perfectly and I was able to follow this workflow and recreate migrations that needed naming changes and more from the PRs. I can delete the migration manually and try to come up with a working new migration but I don't want to break things in the background and I want to do things properly.

When I run it with verbose I get (among the usual enormous amount of messages) the following message that looks not good:

> [...]
> A manual migration deletion was detected.
> [...]

Does this have anything to do with the problems I'm having? Should I just delete all the changes and recreate a new migration from, say, the last moment it worked fine?

I'm using .NET Core 3.1 and SQL Server.

I can also move on a create a new migration that drops the wrongly typed column and replaces it with the new, correct one.

Comment: Are you compiling in VS or from a command prompt?  I think the problem has to due with the compiler dependencies not recognizing when the version of Core (or mapping) file has changed.  Using the command line compiler you get add dependencies so everything get rebuilt.  Or from VS do a clean build.

Comment: @jdweng I'm compiling in a command prompt. Can it be that EF Core no longer removes the migration files?

Comment: Read everything that broke : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.1